# how to parse xml as like json dictionary in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, xml, soap

```
<Data>
<Row>
<Emp_Code>600045</Emp_Code>
<Emp_Name>Partap Singh</Emp_Name>
<ApplicationNo>170</ApplicationNo>
<ApplicationDate>2018-05-17 04:29:54</ApplicationDate>
<LeaveCategory>Annual Leave</LeaveCategory>
<FromDate>2017-06-14</FromDate>
<ToDate>2017-06-14</ToDate>
<No.ofDays>1.0</No.ofDays>
<Status>Cancelled</Status>
<AllowCancel>N</AllowCancel>
</Row>
<Row>
<Emp_Code>600045</Emp_Code>
<Emp_Name>Partap Singh</Emp_Name>
<ApplicationNo>171</ApplicationNo>
<ApplicationDate>2018-05-17 04:33:47</ApplicationDate>
<LeaveCategory>Annual Leave</LeaveCategory>
<FromDate>2017-06-15</FromDate>
<ToDate>2017-06-15</ToDate>
<No.ofDays>1.0</No.ofDays>
<Status>Cancelled</Status>
<AllowCancel>N</AllowCancel>
</Row>
<Row>
<Emp_Code>600045</Emp_Code>
<Emp_Name>Partap Singh</Emp_Name>
<ApplicationNo>172</ApplicationNo>
<ApplicationDate>2018-05-17 06:17:09</ApplicationDate>
<LeaveCategory>Annual Leave</LeaveCategory>
<FromDate>2017-06-16</FromDate>
<ToDate>2017-06-16</ToDate>
<No.ofDays>1.0</No.ofDays>
<AllowCancel>N</AllowCancel>
</Row>
```

Here its my XML response. as I am new in iOS. So I want to parse XML data and store data in  array of dictionary  as like JSON. So please any body tell me how to achieve that task.

Comment: You can use XMLParser and implement `XMLParserDelegate`.

Comment: https://github.com/yahoojapan/SwiftyXMLParser..you can use this.

Comment: https://github.com/yahoojapan/SwiftyXMLParser here is the simple library to parse XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XMLParser or you can also write logic to extract data from xml.

```
let data: Data = ... //response converted in Data(NSData).
let xmlData = XMLParser(data: data)
xmlData.delegate = self
```

Implement `XMLParserDelegate`. There are methods available for different purposes.

```
extension ViewController: XMLParserDelegate {

    public func parserDidStartDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {

    }


    public func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {

    }

    public func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundInternalEntityDeclarationWithName name: String, value: String?) {

    }

   //there are other methods too that can be used.
}
```

Comment: i want store all data in array of dictionary

Comment: Just google about XMLParse you will definitely get an idea how to get data from xml.